# python: Importing mayavi.mlab produces syntax error

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to use mayavi to create 3d plots but when running my python script I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mayavi.mlab
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 15, in <module>
    from mayavi.core.common import process_ui_events
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\common.py", line 16, in <module>
    from apptools.persistence.state_pickler import create_instance
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\apptools\persistence\state_pickler.py", line 1210

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The function i'm trying to test:

```
  def create_3D(dataset):
    #Extract the x, y ,z and von mises data from the numpy dataset and create an array for each.
    xs = dataset[:,1]
    ys = dataset[:,2]
    zs = dataset[:,3]
    v = dataset[:,4]

    # Define the points in 3D space
    # including color code based on value v
    pts = mlab.points3d(xs, ys, zs , v)

    # Triangulate based on X, Y with Delaunay 2D algorithm.
    # Save resulting triangulation.
    mesh = mlab.pipeline.delaunay2d(pts)

    # Remove the point representation from the plot
    pts.remove()

    # Draw a surface based on the triangulation
    surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh)

    # Simple plot.
    mlab.xlabel("x")
    mlab.ylabel("y")
    mlab.zlabel("z")
    mlab.show()
```

Any idea how I could fix this?
I followed the installation procedure suggested [here](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html) 
    $ pip install mayavi

```
$ pip install PyQt5
```

I am using a 64bit version of python 3.7

Comment: While the checked answer says that state_pickler.py is 1022 lines long, the file I got from `pip3.7 install apptools` was about twice that length (likely because of odd line endings) -- so it definitely *did* have a line 1210.  My solution was to uninstall the version I downloaded from pypi and install the version from [Christoph Gohlke's unofficial windows binaries page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state_pickler.py` is only 1022 lines long, it doesn't have line 1210.

Remove the directory `C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\apptools\persistence\__pycache__` and try again.

Try to reinstall `apptools`:

```
pip install -U apptools
```

Comment: I've tried both but the same error is still occuring. I looked at the state_pickler.py file and the one the error is referencing is 2046 lines long.

Comment: I just tried to install `apptools` for Python 2.7 and 3.5 — both brought `state_pickler.py` of 1022 lines. Looks like the file is already corrupted at your disk. Uninstall: `pip uninstall apptools`, delete directories: `xdel C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\apptools*`, reinstall: `pip install -U apptools`.

Comment: On Windows it does have that many lines; somehow all the newlines are doubled. The syntax error comes from lines continued after a backslash, because on Windows there is an empty line between the backslash and the continuation of the line.

Comment: I started to experience the same problem at [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/phdru/m-librarian/builds/22038935) with all my tests under Python 3.7 about a month ago. The workaround was to [copy](https://github.com/phdru/m_librarian/commit/091d82f0243963f5efdffd620cdf46873801aa28) a pristine file to overwrite the broken one. I don't know what causes the problem and how to properly fix it. I cannot reproduce it at home.

Comment: I just had this error. For me, I didn't need to delete or modify any files to fix it. I was in a (mostly) fresh conda environment. I just ran `pip uninstall apptools` and then `pip install -U apptools`, and somehow that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same problem but solved it. seems in the state_pickler.py file, in a few places (where the error message tells, it has \ in in the "if .... \ and " (used to split the and conditions in multiple lines), just to remove the \ to make all the " and " conditions in one line. There are a few places with the issue, then amazingly it work!

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 10, Python 3.7.4 (Anaconda 2019.10)

How Rem says:
"On Windows it does have that many lines; somehow all the newlines are doubled. The syntax error comes from lines continued after a backslash, because on Windows there is an empty line between the backslash and the continuation of the line."

In windows, i only find the file "state_pickler.py" and removed the empty lines after the "\", saved it and all works fine.